# How to Mock with Moq to do foreach row in table

Tags: c#, mocking

I'm a C# and Moq newb. I have some code that looks like the following and I want to unit test it, using Moq.

```
Data.Foo.FooDataTable tbl = Adapter.GetFooByID(id);
foreach (Data.Foo.FooRow row in tbl)
{
    x = row.bar
    ...
}
```

How do I set up the mocks? Current broken attempt:

```
var adapter = new Mock<FooTableAdapter>();
var table = new Mock<Foo.FooDataTable>();
var rows = new Mock<DataRowCollection>();
var row = new Mock<Foo.FooRow>();
rows.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator().Current).Returns(row.Object);
table.Setup(x => x.Rows).Returns(rows.Object);
adapter.Setup(x => x.GetFooByID(1)).Returns(table.Object);
_adapter = adapter.Object;
```

If I don't try to add the row, I get a NullReferenceException in the foreach. If I do try to add the row, I get a System.NotSupportedException: Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.

Answer (score 1):

Mocks are awesome and all but they really are testing tools of last resort -- what you reach for when you've got some impossible to create object you can't avoid depending on -- such as HttpContext.

In this case, you probably don't want to create a moq mock of the DataTable -- you can just new up one with appropriate data. What you'd want to moq mock would be the call to Adapter.GetFooById() to spit back your test double of a data table.

Answer (score 1):

Mocks should only be used to create fake dependencies when you want to test the behaviour of something that requires said dependency, but you don't want (or can't) actually create a "real" instance of that dependency. Any test method with more than a couple of mocks is headed in the wrong direction because it's a sign that you have either too many dependencies, or that you are testing too many unrelated things.

In the code you have above, there are no dependencies, so Mocks wouldn't be appropriate  really what you need.

You really need to think about *what* exactly it is you are trying to test here. For the sake of argument let's assume that the code you showed is from a method:

```
public class MyFooClass
{
   public int DoFooFooData(FooAdapter Foo)
   {
     Data.Foo.FooDataTable tbl = Adapter.GetFooByID(id);
     //just imagining what you might do here.
     int total=0;
     foreach (Data.Foo.FooRow row in tbl)
     {
       x = row.bar
       //just imagining what you might do here.
       total+=x;
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

- Now, let's further suppose that you want to unit test *this method*. In this case in order to call the method you have to supply a working `FooAdapter` instance because the method *depends on it in order to work*
- But let's now say that you are not currently in possession of a `FooAdapter` because it doesn't exist, or maybe you can't supply one because `FooAdapter` makes a database connection which is a no-no in unit testing.

What we need to do in order to test `DoFooFooData` is to supply a fake (Mock) `FooAdapter`, which only implements the `GetFooByID` method, in order for your function to execute.

To do this you'll have to either make `FooAdapter` abstract or (I recommend) declare it by interface:

`public interface IFooAdapter
        {
           Data.Foo.FooDataTable GetByID(int id);
        }`

(later on you'll need to change `FooAdapter` *class* to implement `IFooAdapter` if you want to actually use it with the `DoFooFooData` method for real)

Now change your method signature:

```
public void DoFooFooData(IFooAdapter Foo)
    {
       Data.Foo.FooDataTable tbl = Adapter.GetFooByID(id);
         int total=0;
         foreach (Data.Foo.FooRow row in tbl)
         {
           x = row.bar
           //just imagining what you might do here
           total+=x;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

And finally in your test method, you can mock this dependency:

```
 void DoFooFooData_DoesSomeFooAndReturns3()
    {
      var mock = new Mock<IFooAdapter>();
      var table = new Data.Foo.FooDataTable();
      table.Add(new Data.Foo.FowRow{bar=1});
      table.Add(new Data.Foo.FowRow{bar=2});
      mock.Setup(m=>m.GetByID(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(table);

      var sut = new MyFooClass();
      var expected=3;
      var actual=sut.DoFooFooData(mock.Object);
      Assert.AreEqual(expected,actual);
    }
```

Of course if you need to Mock `FooDataTable` as well you can follow the same pattern as you did with the `IFooAdapter` but you need to stop at this point and ask yourself if you shouldn't be creating a *separate test* in which you Mock an `IFooDataTable` and ensure that it does what it's supposed to do (Add method or whatever) and so on...at the point when you were sure that the behavioural contract of `IFooDataTable` is OK, you'd then implement it as a concrete "stub" which you can then use in place of any `FooDataTable` references in the context of an `IFooAdapter`...but now you're into integration tests which is a story for another day...